# how can i find data atrribute in jquery

Tags: jquery

Html

```
  <span class="unread" id="@item.TaskId" data-id="read"> @item.Title</span><br />
```

jquery

```
$("#notificationsBody > span").find("[data-id='read']").attr('class', 'read');
```

How can find all the data-id in this code and set their class to read? the above line is not working

Comment: Have you tried `.addClass('read')`?

Comment: i want you people to take a look at find also

Comment: Is it the span that has the `data-id` or a children of the span?

Answer (score 1):

Since it's the span that has the `data-id`, you can't use `.find()` since it search for decendants. Use `.filter()` instead, or better, put it in the selector.

You might also want to use `.addClass()` instead of `.attr()`

```
$("#notificationsBody > span[data-id='read']").addClass('read');
```

If you have to remove the class `unread`, you can chain `.removeClass()`

```
$("#notificationsBody > span[data-id='read']")
  .addClass('read');
  .removeClass('unread');
```

Answer (score 0):

find() goes through in deep of children. But, children() goes through the first level of children.

```
$("#notificationsBody").chlidren("span[data-id='read']").addClass('read').removeClass('unread');
```

Answer (score 0):

In optimum way

```
$("#notificationsBody span[data-id='read']").addClass("read").removeClass("unread");
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run your code and he works.

```js
$('.activate').click(function() {
 $("#notificationsBody > span").find("[data-id='read']").attr('class', 'read');
});
```

```css
li {
 display:none;
}
.read {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="notificationsBody">
  <span>
    <ul>
      <li data-id="read">a</li>
      <li data-id="read">b</li>
    </ul>
  </span>
</div>
<button class="activate">Add read class</button>
```